# iterator that skips, steps by and returns correct index

Tags: rust, iterator, enumerate

I am writing a program which needs an iterator which starts at the `nth` value in an array and steps by `m` giving the correct index (`n + xm`) of the element. Currently my code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut test = [false; 10];

    for (index, val) in test.iter_mut().skip(3).step_by(2).enumerate() {
        *val = true;
        println!("{index} = true")
    }

    println!("{:?}", test)
}

// -> 
// 0 = true
// 1 = true
// 2 = true
// 3 = true
// [false, false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true]
```

gives the correct element (`val`) but the wrong index (`index`). For example the first line of output should be `3 = true`. Could you please let me know how to get the correct `index`'s?

Thanks,

Comment: Enumerate before skipping

Comment: sure, I’ll do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: ***Enumerate before skipping***.

Operations on iterators (instances that implement [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html)) are sequential. They work lazily, by applying another type that calls inner’s `next` and then performs it’s own operation. What I’m trying to tell is that ***order of operations matters***. With this knowledge you now can just put enumeration to the beginning of this operation pipe:

```rust
test.iter_mut()
    .enumerate()
    .skip(3)
    .step_by(2)
    .for_each(|(index, val)| {
        *val = true;
        println!("{index} = true");
    });
```